# Can I assign a #define value to Char*?

Tags: pointers, memory, memory-leaks, char, structure

I have been writing a C - programm. Where I have a structure with char* members.

```
#define SS_Value_1 "Value for SS1"
#define SS_Value_1 "Value for SS2"

struct aSamplestruct {

char* s1;
char* s2;

}aSample;

aSample ss;

fun1( &aSample );
```

I am sending the structure point to a function and I know the best practice is to allocate memory to S1 and copy the string what ever we want and free the allocated memory after usage, As shown below

```
ss->s1 = (char*) MEM_alloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(SS_Value_1) + 1);
strcpy(ss->s1, SS_Value_1);
```

use the variable ss.s1 in a report and do mem free.

```
MEM_free(ss.s1);
```

Its working fine no worries. but I have to write the same piece of code for some 10 char* members in 36 different conditions.

The other way is that, without allocating any memory I am able to directly assign the #define values to my structure members as below.

```
ss->s1 = SS_Value_1;
```

use this variable in a report and no need to free any memory.
this way also fine, no problems in a sample execution.

what I would like to know is

> whether this will cause any memory leaks ?
>   will it stop executing for large data ?

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Sudhir

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to 
char *str;
str = "abc";

That is, you are declaring a char pointer, creating a string literal and assigning its address to the pointer. should work for any amount of data.